# How to open port 80 on Mac?

Tags: tcp, ip, tcpclient, tcplistener

I want to send application logs from mobile device via tcp-socket. I put listener with nc -l -k 80 command in Mac's terminal. But port 80 is closed on Mac. How can I open port 80?

And other question about my IP address:
With web check tool, I receive that my IP is : 89.xxx.xx.196 
I think that it should began from 196 and not from 89. Why it is opposite and how can I receive the none-oposite my IP?

Comment: The 89.xxx.xx.196 IP is the WAN network IP of your gateway (router or modem).  The 192.xxx... IP is your LAN IP.

Comment: You can use `ipconfig` in terminal to get your LAN IP address.

Comment: @Michael can I send tcp socket to 89.xx.. IP address or I should to send to 192.xxx IP address? And ipconfig doesn't works on mac. I tried ifconfig command or to look in the Preferences , but it gives only "xx:xx:xx.." addresses.

Comment: Sorry I meant `ifconfig`.  I forgot that it was different :).  You'll need to clear up the question a little. Are you trying to send something from a mobile device to your Mac OS X machine?  Do you have a static IP? Do you have a domain?

Comment: @Michael yes, exactly, I want to send logs from mobile device to my Mac Lion OS X and to see them in Terminal window. I think that I have a static IP and I don't have a domain.

Comment: How do you know port 80 is closed? What's the output of `netstat -an | grep 80.*LISTEN` and `ps auwx | grep nc`?

Comment: @Mark the first command gives: tcp46 0   0  *.80   *.*  LISTEN. The second command gives 5 processes with total %CPU = 0 and total %MEM = 0.2 . I think that port 80 is closed on my Mac because when I check with any web scan-port-program my IPv4 Ip Address for port 80 connection, I get that my port 80 doesn't responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your `netstat` output indicates that the netcat listener is running and the port is open. To perform a local test, on your MBP, run `telnet 127.0.0.1 80` and you should be able to connect like so -

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 80
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Your mobile device (I'm presuming) is on the same wireless) as the MBP. Therefore, as alluded to by Michael Graczyk, you need to connect to the MBP IP address on the internal network (`ifconfig en1`), which is the 192.x.x.x IP address. If you can run `telnet 192.x.x.x 80` where 192.x.x.x is the IP of the MAC and get a connected prompt, then all is ok. If you get nothing and the simply the CLI is returned, then there's something in between blocking or dropping the port 80 connection attempt. It is possible that your WAN router needs an ACL rule on it to allow the connection.

If the mobile device is on an external network, you'll need to connect to 89.x.x.x (on your WAN router) and enable port forwarding (most likely) on port 80 on the router.